# Arrange multiple checkboxes like a grid. Without tables?

Tags: html, css, forms, layout, checkbox

I'm currently working on a big formular with a lot of checkboxes.
Is there a way to display them like a grid, e.g. 4 columns?

I know you can do this with tables but I don't really want to use them to style things if it is not really necessary. So is there a way with CSS?

Example:
[]text []text []text []text 
[]text []text []text []text 
...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here is a solution, with complete checkbox markup and **CSS**, and a working example.

```css
.checkbox-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.checkbox-grid li {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="checkbox-grid">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="text1" value="value1" /><label for="text1">Text 1</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="text2" value="value2" /><label for="text2">Text 2</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="text3" value="value3" /><label for="text3">Text 3</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="text4" value="value4" /><label for="text4">Text 4</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="text5" value="value5" /><label for="text5">Text 5</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="text6" value="value6" /><label for="text6">Text 6</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="text7" value="value7" /><label for="text7">Text 7</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="text8" value="value8" /><label for="text8">Text 8</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Changing the display to block is unnecessary when floating, as floating automatically changes the display property of the element.

Comment: That may be true, however I like to ensure the element is properly set to a block just in case.  Given my experience with developing for IE, it's better to be specific when it comes to these things.

Comment: If you use "inline-block" instead of "float", you don't have to clear after.

Comment: Is it possible to do this where the grid adjusts to the screen size? Like if the screen gets smaller it goes from 4 columns to 3 columns, etc?

Comment: Yes. You can use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) to adjust the CSS based on screen size.

Answer (score 4):

The columns property is a fine choice for this task, since you can make it responsive very easily.

http://jsfiddle.net/FmV9k/1/ (prefixes not included)

```
.checkboxes {
    columns: 4 8em;
}


<ul class="checkboxes">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="text1" value="value1" />Text 1</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="text2" value="value2" />Text 2</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="text3" value="value3" />Text 3</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="text4" value="value4" />Text 4</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="text5" value="value5" />Text 5</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="text6" value="value6" />Text 6</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="text7" value="value7" />Text 7</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="text8" value="value8" />Text 8</label></li>
</ul>
```

We've specified 4 columns, but they must be a minimum of 8em wide.  If there's not enough room for all 4 columns, then it will remove columns as necessary to ensure the minumum width is met.

Comment: CSS3 columns are not supported by IE.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#multicolumn

Comment: In theory, yes, but check [the current availability of this style](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn).

Comment: This method is preferred if you don't want your items to snake around left to right then up to down.  This places items top to bottom first, then left to right.

Answer (score 3):

Try ul li

```
<div>
<ul class="chk">
<li>checkbox</li>
<li>checkbox</li>
<li>checkbox</li>
<li>checkbox</li>

<li>checkbox</li>
<li>checkbox</li>
<li>checkbox</li>
<li>checkbox</li>

</ul>
</div>


.chk 
{
  width:100%;
}
.chk li
{
   display:inline-block;
   width:25%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with "`float:left;display:table-cell`" and pseudo class "`:nth-child`" and "`float:none`"

check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/7gdgQ/1/ (is commented)

And good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use div's and such to do so, don't be afraid of tables though.  They do have pertinent applications and you should use them if what your trying to do warrants using them.

Here is a div based css solution: http://jsfiddle.net/XugFX/

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" /><label>Box 1</label></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" /><label>Box 2</label></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" /><label>Box 3</label></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" /><label>Box 4</label></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" /><label>Box 5</label></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" /><label>Box 6</label></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" /><label>Box 7</label></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" /><label>Box 8</label></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
}

.col {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Tables are for tabular data, not content structuring.  So using a table for this request wouldn't make sense semantically.

Answer (score 0):

You can float the checkboxes and give each a width of 25% of the parent container.

Comment: shouldn't you wrap them first?